# Custom directive for HTTP validation, show popup if partial match found

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to match an input against a service side REST API to see if it is valid but, if it is invalid (and you are currently typing) it can present a list of options for you to choose from.

I have already implemented this in jQuery but need to implement in AngularJS.  Would this be best as a custom directive or a set of functions on the controller?

If I went the custom directive route how would I make this validate and also provide a list to (something) to display.  All the display code I can do, im mostly concerned about how to structure and create the code.

(Untested / pseudo) code

```
m.directive('validDevice', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, c) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/api/check/' + attrs.validDevice,
                    data: { 'device': attrs.validDevice }
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
                    c.$setValidity('validDevice', data.length == 1);

                    // Partials listed here here if data.length > 1
                    // What binds to this? Is this the best place to put this?
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, cfg) {
                    c.$setValidity('validDevice', false);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

As per Monsiour Toph (epic name)'s suggestions Ive created a directive to do the validation, which works, and am trying to use `typeahead` for the auto suggest list, but when I implement this literally nothing happens, an ajax call is never made and a box never pops up.  I copied the code directly from the example (so should load locations)

```
    <input id="deviceToOperateOn"
           name="deviceToOperateOn"
           type="text"
           placeholder="Device Serial"
           ng-show="operatesOnSelector == 1"
           ng-model="device"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }"
           valid-device="{{device}}"
           typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to this wonderfull module : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Especially the last feature at bottom of the page : **Typeahead**

As far as I understand your need, this is almost what you are trying to implement (the suggestions list) ...

After that, use a custom directive to set the validity of the field.

---

**EDIT:**

Demo for typeahead directive + ngModel.$validators : http://jsfiddle.net/msieurtoph/gqu60d0c/2/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as c"> 
    <pre>scope.device = {{device}}</pre>
    <input id="deviceToOperateOn" 
           name="deviceToOperateOn" 
           type="text" 
           placeholder="Device Serial" 
           ng-show="operatesOnSelector == 1" 
           ng-model="device" 
           valid-device 
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }" 
           typeahead="value for value in values | filter:$viewValue" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.operatesOnSelector = 1;
    $scope.device = '';
    $scope.values = [
        'phone', 'tv', 'desktop', 'washing machine'];
});

app.directive('validDevice', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, ele, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$validators.validDevice = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;

                console.log('validator validDevice is running for value : ', value);
                console.log('set to : ', scope.values.indexOf(value) !== -1);
                return scope.values.indexOf(value) !== -1;

            };

        }
    }
}]);
```

Think about :

- adding 'ui.bootstrap' to the main module dependency injection.
- linking to the bootstrap css and angular-bootstrap js sheets
- **RTFM !!** ... instead of dummy copy-pasting the code, and complain : 'it does not work'.

By the way, your code seems really really strange.

As I said, POST verb shouldn't be used for 'checking' operations. You don't even need to request server, if you already have the list of suggestions (= the list of possible values) ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Typeahead wont work because bootstrap doesnt work with Angular 1.3 which is what im using.  Secondly this isnt production code (yet) im just testing, so I left the POST verb there simply to try get something working before I refactored.  I have it working as part of the controller rather than using a custom directive

Comment: Odd, wouldnt work for me and also : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2474